# Particle (made with constructor) expand and fade upon collision

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, particle-system, p5.js

When a user clicks on any particle I want it to expand and fade and upon collision with any other particle and that particle will also expand and fade. Now my problem is that I want to know if there is a way in which I can get those particles (made with constructor in this case) to effect each other when they get collide. Link to  [Codepen](https://codepen.io/prvnbist/pen/QvoVPw)

```js
var bubbles = [];

function setup() {
 frameRate(25);
 // Creates Canvas
 createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
 //Genrates 100 Particles with random a & y
 for (var i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
  var x = random(width);
  var y = random(height);
  bubbles[i] = new Bubble(x, y);
 }
}

function mousePressed() {
 for (var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
  bubbles[i].clicked();
 }
}

function draw() {
 clear();
 //Adds color and motion
 for (var bubble of bubbles) {
  fill(bubble.color.red, bubble.color.green, bubble.color.blue);
  bubble.move();
  bubble.display();
 }
}

function Bubble(x, y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.wh = 15;
 this.speedX = random(1, 5);
 this.speedY = random(1, 5);

 //Individual Particle Creation
 this.display = function() {
  noStroke();
  ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.wh, this.wh);
 };

 //Interactivity
 this.clicked = function() {
  var d = dist(this.x, this.y, mouseX, mouseY);
  if (d < 8) {
   this.wh = 100;
  }
 };

 //Randomizes colors
 this.color = {
  red: random(255),
  green: random(255),
  blue: random(255)
 };

 //Particle Motion
 this.move = function() {
  //Motion in X direction
  this.x += this.speedX;

  //Bouncing back on X-axis
  if (this.x > windowWidth || this.x < 0) {
   this.speedX = -this.speedX;
  }
  //Motion in Y Direction
  this.y += this.speedY;
  //Bouncing back on Y-axis
  if (this.y > windowHeight || this.y < 0) {
   this.speedY = -this.speedY;
  }
 };
}

function windowResized() {
 resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.10/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Loop over bubbles and loop over bubbles. If the bubble is not the same, check for collision...

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested `for` loop.

**Step 1:** Loop over the bubbles. Do this with a `for` loop.

**Step 2:** For each bubble, loop over the rest of the bubbles (if you're on bubble 4, start with bubble 5). Do this with another `for` loop inside the first one.

**Step 3:** Now that you have two bubbles, do the collision between them.

If you're having trouble getting that working, then please start smaller. Start with a simpler program that just shows two hard-coded bubbles and does [collision detection](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) between them.